# Google Analytics 4 and hitCallback

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Previously with Universal Google Analytics i used sometimes the option to send `hitCallback` function when tracking custom events:

```
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'Some Category',
    eventAction: 'Some Action',
    eventLabel: 'Some Label',
    eventValue: 'Some Value',
    hitCallback() {
        console.log('event sent for sure!');
    }

});
```

this gave me the ability to ensure the event has been tracked in case i have redirection to another page afterwards.

I'm trying to find a way to do it with Google Analytics 4 but cannot find a standard parameter to send to `gtag('event' ...)` that will do the same.

It is crutial as from my experience many events are lost due to redirection especiually important ones like register or login.

Answer (score 5):

Somehow after few hours of search i found it very quick after posting this one, so instead of deleting it it might be helpful for others.

The parameter it `event_callback` you can read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/parameters